# Function close to zero on $-\infty$ and close to $y = x$ on $+\infty$

Tags: limits, functions, asymptotics

I'm looking for monotonic function $f(x)$, with properties 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = x$$
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x) = 0$$
$$f''(x) >0$$ 
How can I define such a function ?

Comment: I guess you mean $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x} = 1$. Can you draw such a function?

Comment: Limits *equal* something; they don't *converge* to something.

Comment: You probably meant that you wanted either$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}x=1$$Or$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)-x=0$$

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

$$f(x)=\frac12(\sqrt{1+x^2}+x)$$

As $x\to\pm\infty$, $\sqrt{1+x^2}\sim|x|$, so $f(x)\sim_\infty\frac12(x+x)=x$ and $f(x)\sim_{-\infty}\frac12(-x+x)=0$

Comment: What about $f'' > 0$

Comment: @Youem It is also satisfied. Not to hard to evaluate the derives directly.

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: Just for fun, this is a hyperbola with the equation $y^2=\frac14 (1+4xy)$.

Comment: @Joel Ofc, where do you think I got the idea?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I know why you thought of it. I actually enjoy your answers when I see them. I just felt like working out the equation myself, and thought it might be helpful to the OP.

Comment: Cool and thanks for the support $\ddot\smile$ I don't see you around often, but feel free to join my [random chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51337/this-is-the-realm-of-simply-beautiful-art) and/or my [analysis chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54911/simply-beautiful-arts-realm-of-calculus-and-analysis) if you want.

Answer (score 3):

Another simple one:
$$
f(x) = \ln(1+e^x)
.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be defined as :

$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 
x + \frac{1}{x+1} & x \ge 0\\
\frac{1}{x^2+1} & x < 0
\end{array}\right.$